# Automated regression procedure in Stata

Tags: stata, linear-regression

I'm going to study the relationship between the illiquidity and returns in stock markets, using the Amihud model proposed in the paper "Illiquidity and stock returns: cross-section and time-series effects" (2002). I would like to know if it is possible to automate the regression analysis. I've have more than 2000 stocks in the sample and I'd like to avoid to run each regression one-by-one, speeding the process up.
Do you know if it is possible automate this process in Stata? or if is it possible to do that using some other statistical software (R, SAS, Matlab, Gretl,...) ? If it is, how could I do that?

Comment: You are cutting down your readership by expecting that mentioning the title of a paper alone is enough to make your aim clear. Better practice on any list or forum is to give more details or at a minimum a much better reference. There is no sign here that you have tried to work on code at all in any language.

Comment: I didn't ask anything about the paper. I simply asked if there exist a code that allow me to run the regressions automatically. I mean: I have a regression model like for instance Yit= a + b*Xit; I have to run that several times for every i at time t in the sample.My question is: do I have to run the regressions one-by-one, or does exist a code in stata (or in others software) that allow me to run those regression only one time? I don't know the code, but I think that it is possible!

Comment: Particularly, in my case I have a stock sample i, where i=stock1,stock2,stock3,.... Do I have to run on stata regress Ystock1=a+b*Xstock1, regress Ystock2=a+b*Xstock2 or does it exist a code that allow me not to write every regression one-by-one manually? like for instance a macro in excel. Thanks and sorry for this stupid question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `foreach` and `forval` as ways of looping.

```
 forval i = 1/3 { 
     regress Ystock`i' Xstock`i' 
 }
```

would be an example if and only if there are variables with names like those you indicated. If you have other names, or a different data structure, a loop would still be possible.